# Random walk forecast with drift model

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I am trying to produce a random walk with drift forecast using the forecast package as described [here](https://otexts.org/fpp2/simple-methods.html). Setting the number of periods for forecasting `h = 2` works fine, but not `h = 1` as in the example below:

```
library(forecast)
drift <- rwf(AirPassengers, h = 1, drift = TRUE)
```

> non-intersecting seriesnon-intersecting series

Or without saving the object:

```
rwf(AirPassengers, h = 1, drift = TRUE)
```

> Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations

The  `wineind` dataset in the forecast package also returns this error, whereas `woolyrnq` does not. Datasets `airmiles` and `BJsales` in base R work fine too.

Comment: This problem does not occur in v8.5 on github (https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast).  Presumably it is a bug that has already been fixed.

Comment: Thanks, version 8.5 solved the problem.